# How to remove the comma seperated part of the column record from the oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

We have the oracle table called "Names" which has approximately 10k records. The table has one of the column as "ID". Now this column is totally messed up and the records looks somewhat similar to the following.

```
ID
A.011
A.012
A.013
B.014
B.015
B.016
A-B-C
X_Y_Z

randomName
OtherName
```

Now, what we have decided is to remove the dot(.) seperated portion of the record and leave the other records as is for now. So the record should look like

```
ID
011
012
013
014
015
016
A-B-C
X_Y_Z
randomName
OtherName
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Do you have more than one "." in the ID column values? For example - "A.B.C" In this case what should be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this statement:

```
update names set id=regexp_replace(id,'^[^\.]+\.','')
```

as you see here, ids without `.` are simply untouched:

```
select regexp_replace('tst234','^[^\.]+\.','') from dual
```

and here a test with a `.`

```
select regexp_replace('A.0234','^[^\.]+\.','') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression:

```
update names set id = case
                        when instr(id,'.') between 0 and length(id) - 1 then
                          regexp_replace(id,'^[^\.]*\.(.+)$','\1')
                        else id
                      end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To `UPDATE` use this simple query:

```
UPDATE Name
   SET ID = SUBSTR(ID, INSTR(ID, '.')+1);
```

[See **SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92d46/1)

P.S. Although it's kinda weird, that `SUBSTR(expr, 0) = SUBSTR(expr,1)`. But it works!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following sql query, which will remove your `.` from the string.

```
UPDATE Names SET ID = regexp_replace(id,'\.+','');
```

Below query will remove all the character, which comes before `.`

```
UPDATE Names SET ID = substr(id,instr(id,'.')+1);
```

Comment: I think he wants to remove from the beginning til including the ".".

Comment: @wumpz added one more sql query.